# Bernoulli's equation(differential equations)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following equation:
$$\sec^2y\frac{dy}{dx}+x \tan y =x^3$$
I have tried like this:
Let, tan y  =z
$$\implies \sec^2 y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dx}\\$$
$$\therefore \frac{dz}{dx}+zx=x^3\\$$
$$I.F.=e^{\int{xdx}}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\\$$
 $$\therefore ze^{\frac{x^2}{2}} =\int{x^3 e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx}\\$$
$$=2(\frac{x^2}{2} e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}-e^{\frac{x^2}{2}})+c\\$$
$$\therefore \tan y e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(x^2-2)+c\\$$
$$\implies \tan y=x^2-2+ce^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$
But in my book the answer is:
$$\tan y=x^3-3x^2+6x-6+ce^{-x}$$
I can't understand where is my mistake..please check this..

Comment: Actually you will have to itegrate $x^3\times e^{x^2}$

Comment: I checked your attempts but it's a bit hard to read  I got the same answer as yours so I guess there is a mistake in your book

Comment: @Isham where you can't understand tell me...I will try to edit there

Comment: I refreeshed the page its ok now I got the same answer so there is no mistake in your answer

Comment: @Isham ok then

Comment: +1 Yes it's correct don"t bother sometimes book have wrong answers...By the way why the Bernouilli's title ? It's not a Bernouilli's equation

Comment: @Isham in my book the sum was under the quotation "Bernoulli's equation "...so I wrote the title mentioning that...

Comment: I see ...Maybe they made a msitake in the DE ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(\tan y )'+x \tan y =x^3$$
Substitute $z=\tan y$
$$z'+xz=x^3$$
$$(ze^{x^2/2})'=x^3e^{x^2/2}$$
$$ze^{x^2/2}=\int x^3e^{x^2/2} dx$$
Substitute $u=\dfrac {x^2}2$
$$ze^{x^2/2}=2\int ue^{u} du$$
$$ze^{x^2/2}=2( ue^{u}.-e^u)+C $$
$$z=2(\frac {x^2}2-1)+Ce^{-x^2/2}$$
Finally:
$$ \boxed {\tan y= {x^2}-2+Ce^{-x^2/2}}$$

Comment: Yes, I also did that but the book's answer is different...so I am confused